# Option added to the bottom of options in MUI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am building a category adder and previously I was only allowing the "add category chip" to show for the nooptions render, but I realized that if there was a category "software ngineer" and someone wanted to add "Software" you couldn't do it.

Ultimately I want to add the Add chip (which is different then the normal chips) to the end of all of the options with the search term in it. I tried adding it to the render option, but then it showed up after every option and I tried adding it to filter options but then I can't customize that chip.

Any suggestions on solving this?

My code:

```js
<Autocomplete
                id="Categories"
                // set it to the left of the cell
                style={{ width: '100%', marginTop: '1rem' }}
                key={autocompleteKey}
                options={
                  user.categories.length > 0
                    ? user.categories.filter((c) => {
                      return !category.includes(c || c.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + c.slice(1));
                    })
                    : []
                }
                onChange={(event, value) => (handleAddCategoryToCompany(value))}
                onInputChange={(event, value) => setNewCategory(value)}
                popupIcon=""
                filterOptions={(options) => {
                  console.log(options);
                  const result = [...options];
                  if (search.length > 0) result.push(search);
                  return result;
                }}
                renderOption={(event, value: string) => (
                  <>
                    <Chip
                      variant="outlined"
                      sx={{
                        m: '2px',
                      }}
                      onClick={() => handleAddCategoryToCompany(value)}
                      key={Math.random()}
                      label={value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)}
                      onDelete={() => removeFromGlobal(value)}
                    />
                    {/* {search.length > 0
                      ? (
                        <Chip
                          variant="outlined"
                          onClick={handleAddCategory}
                          key={Math.random()}
                          sx={{
                            m: '2px',
                          }}
                          label={search}
                          icon={<AddCircleIcon />}
                        />
                      ) : null} */}
                  </>
                )}
                renderInput={(par) => (
                  // Textfield where the options have a delete icon
                  <TextField
                    {...par}
                    fullWidth
                    label="Add Tag(s)"
                    margin="normal"
                    size="small"
                    name="Name"
                    onChange={(event) => (setSearch(event.target.value))}
                    key={autocompleteKey}
                    type="company"
                    value={search}
                    variant="outlined"
                  />
                )}
                noOptionsText={search.length > 0
                  ? (
                    <Chip
                      variant="outlined"
                      onClick={handleAddCategory}
                      key={Math.random()}
                      sx={{
                        m: '2px',
                      }}
                      label={search}
                      icon={<AddCircleIcon />}
                    />
                  ) : null}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by adding a modifier to the search option in the filter options and then had a conditional statement in render to look for this option. Seems to be working.

```js
<Autocomplete
                id="Categories"
                // set it to the left of the cell
                style={{ width: '100%', marginTop: '1rem' }}
                key={autocompleteKey}
                options={
                  user.categories.length > 0
                    ? user.categories.filter((c) => {
                      return !category.includes(c || c.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + c.slice(1));
                    })
                    : []
                }
                onChange={(event, value) => (handleAddCategoryToCompany(value))}
                onInputChange={(event, value) => setNewCategory(value)}
                popupIcon=""
                filterOptions={(options) => {
                  console.log(options);
                  const result = [...options];
                  if (search.length > 0) result.push(`${search} (new)`);
                  return result;
                }}
                renderOption={(event, value: string) => (
                  <>
                    {value.indexOf(' (new)') > -1
                      ? (
                        <Chip
                          variant="outlined"
                          onClick={handleAddCategory}
                          key={Math.random()}
                          sx={{
                            m: '2px',
                          }}
                          label={search}
                          icon={<AddCircleIcon />}
                        />
                      )
                      : (
                        <Chip
                          variant="outlined"
                          sx={{
                            m: '2px',
                          }}
                          onClick={() => handleAddCategoryToCompany(value)}
                          key={Math.random()}
                          label={value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)}
                          onDelete={() => removeFromGlobal(value)}
                        />
                      )}
                  </>
                )}
                renderInput={(par) => (
                  // Textfield where the options have a delete icon
                  <TextField
                    {...par}
                    fullWidth
                    label="Add Tag(s)"
                    margin="normal"
                    size="small"
                    name="Name"
                    onChange={(event) => (setSearch(event.target.value))}
                    key={autocompleteKey}
                    type="company"
                    value={search}
                    variant="outlined"
                  />
                )}
                noOptionsText={search.length > 0
                  ? (
                    <Chip
                      variant="outlined"
                      onClick={handleAddCategory}
                      key={Math.random()}
                      sx={{
                        m: '2px',
                      }}
                      label={search}
                      icon={<AddCircleIcon />}
                    />
                  ) : null}
              />
```